# HLS preset settings for 480p | 720p | 1080p

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, http-live-streaming, amazon-elastic-transcoder

We are trying to transcode mp4 videos into HLS using AWS transcoder. We see that there are only few presets available (`highest being 2M`). The max resolution this gives us is 360p on `JWPlayer`.

If we want higher resolution (`480p | 720p | 1080p`), we understand that we need to `transcode` videos at higher bit rate. For that we will need to create new presets.

Could someone help us with different `transcoder` settings to create these presets? We don't understand most of the fields presented in the presets.

Thanks

Comment: You should ask on http://video.stackexchange.com. If you want to estimate the bitrate, level etc. I made a free [android app](http://www.amazon.com/Vlad-Tarca-H-264-AVC-Calculator/dp/B013IF1H2I). Read this to see how to use it: http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/Featured-Articles/How-to-Produce-High-Quality-H.264-Video-Files-94216.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the fasted way to remedy this issue would be to take an existing high definition preset, and alter it to the HLS format. To do this, got the Presets and click on the magnifying lens left of the "System preset: Full HD 1080i60  MP4" preset, and select "Copy" from the top left. From there I would may the following changes:

- Container: .ts
- (Profile: main or high -- experiment :) )
- Interlace mode (auto)
- Sizing Policy (choose to what you believe is best(1) -- the "2M" preset was using 1024x768 res. Shrink to fit, for reference.)
- (optionally remove watermark settings, using the -Watermark on the left hand side of the page.
- And click "Create Preset".

If you would like more information about the preset configuration values, this guide(2) gives a good overview of what each value means.

(1) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/aspect-ratios.html
(2) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/preset-settings.html#preset-settings-video