# 720p and 1080p HLS AWS Elastic Transcoder preset

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am trying to encode video to the HLS format in 720p and 1080p resolution. AWS only has preconfigured presets for video quality up until 1024x767 (System preset: HLS 2M).

Could anyone help me with the exact configuration?

Comment: I know about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954083/hls-preset-settings-for-480p-720p-1080p and I could also try testing with those settings, but I want to get an exact answer so we can have it here for reference. If no answers come in then I will research based on the existing data on the internet, and post the exact configuration here